# Unable to get p256dh key from PushSubscription in Firefox 44.0

Tags: firefox, push-notification, web-push

I was trying to subscribe for Push Notifications from the Service Worker, but I am unable to get the `auth` and `p256dh` keys from the `PushSubscription` object in Firefox 44. This works fine on Firefox 54.

For example, I tried visiting https://gauntface.github.io/simple-push-demo/ on FF 44 and FF 54, here are the differences in the PushSubscription object:

FF44
[image: FF 44]

FF54
[image: FF 54]

I tried using `getKey('p256dh')` on the `PushSubscription` object, but it's returning `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the first versions of the Push API only allowed you to send a signal without a payload, then you have to fetch the notifications from your server. The `auth` and `p256dh` keys were introduced later to support payloads.